# Different behavior when opening a UTF-8 file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, ascii

I am trying to read a file (https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) which contains semantic vector representation of 42B tokens. I use the following code in my local PC environment:

```
import numpy as np
def loadGloveModel(gloveFile):
    print("Loading Glove Model")
    f = open(gloveFile,'r')
    model = {}
    print(f)
    for line in f:
        splitLine = line.split()
        word = splitLine[0]
        embedding = np.array([float(val) for val in splitLine[1:]])
        model[word] = embedding
    print("Done.",len(model)," words loaded!")
    return model

fileDir = './glove.42B.300d.txt'    
glove_model = loadGloveModel(fileDir)
print(len(glove_model['shih-tzu']))
```

And it works. I use jupyter notebook and python3. I think this file is encoded using 'utf-8'.

However, since the further calculations are heavy, I want to run the code on our server. 
First I tried to run the same code (by converting ipython notebook to .py file), but I faced this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa3' in
>   position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

Then I tried the following:

```
   f = open(gloveFile,'r', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Again I received the same error

> File "Spectral_dictionary_based-onlythoseintheglove.py", line 22, in
>   loadGloveModel
>       print(splitLine) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa3' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

I wonder why the same code runs correctly in one environment while is not working in another.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Python are you running on the server?

Comment: The error occurs on *output*, not on input…!

Comment: It is your  terminal that is speaking ASCII! Have Python write to a file instead.

Comment: What the others said, and: it must be the `print()` expression that causes the exception (probably the last one). The encoding of `sys.stdout` depends on the locale and other environment variables of the host machine.

Comment: Oh, it even tells you in the traceback: the offensive line is `print(splitLine)` – a line that is missing from your example code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have realized the problem was for the output (print) and when I removed the line the problem was solved. Thanks a lot.